# QListView: how to add dynamic padding to the bottom?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlistview

My QListView has different type of items, specifically it has `section`s that groups other items below them like:

[image]

What I need, is to be able to scroll QListView to the point, where only one last section is visible, like:

[image]

Basically, I need some spacing at the bottom, with dynamic `height = listView.viewPort().width() - lastSection.height()`.

How this can be achieved with Qt?

Comment: How about listview.viewPort().resize()? You could also add the list view to another QScrollArea and add spacing below the list view. Also consider using a QTreeView or QToolBox.

Comment: @SteakOverflow nice suggestions, thank you. Will try it in a bit and let you know of the results